# Duplicate rows in grid view

Tags: c#, asp.net

Before I have a question about how (Dynamically adding and deleting rows from ASP.NET Grid View), I receive my answer by using article (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/467788/Dynamically-adding-and-deleting-rows-from-ASP-NET).
In this article we add rows when we complete fields by type (hand).
Now I like to complete some fields of row after selecting the value from drop down list, so I have used

```
  public static List<string> Docprpp = new List<string>(3);
```

For the adding first row I have no problem , when I select document  from drop down list I can have (document no,rev,title) in the fields and for other fields I fill by hand.

```
dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["Col1"] = Docprpp[0];
                dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["Col2"] = Docprpp[1];
                dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["Col3"] = Docprpp[2];
                dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["Col4"] = TextBoxsh.Text;
                dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["Col5"] = DrpStatus.SelectedValue;
                dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["Col6"] = DrpClass.SelectedValue;
                rowIndex++;
            }
            dtCurrentTable.Rows.Add(drCurrentRow);
            ViewState["CurrentTable"] = dtCurrentTable;

            grvdocumentDetails.DataSource = dtCurrentTable;
            grvdocumentDetails.DataBind();

        }
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Write("ViewState is null");
    }

    Docprpp.Clear();
    SetPreviousData();

}
```

But I like to add second or more rows and use different values from drop down list but it copes for all the rows (old, new) same (document no, rev, title) according to the picture.

```
 (public static List<string> Docprpp = new List<string>(3);)
```

Please help how I have to use this variable and solve my problem.
[image]

```
 protected void ddlProjectDocument_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (_DataContext = new EDMSDataContext())
    {
        int x = Convert.ToInt32(ddlProjectDocument.SelectedValue);
        var subject = from y in _DataContext.tblDocuments
                      where y.DocId == x
                      select y.TITLE;

        var docno = from z in _DataContext.tblDocuments
                    where z.DocId == x
                    select z.DocumentNo;




        Docprpp.Add(docno.SingleOrDefault().ToString());



        var MaxRev = _DataContext.tblTransmittalls.Where(rev => rev.DocID == x).Max(rev => rev.REV);
        int newRev = (MaxRev == null) ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(MaxRev) + 1;

        Docprpp.Add(newRev.ToString());

        var MaxReview = _DataContext.Project_Documents.Where(rev => rev.DocId == x && rev.Rev == Convert.ToInt32(MaxRev)).Max(rev => rev.Review);
        int newReview = (MaxReview == null) ? newReview = 1 : Convert.ToInt32(MaxReview) + 1;

        Docprpp.Add(subject.SingleOrDefault().ToString());

    }
}

 private void AddNewRow()
{
    int rowIndex = 0;

    if (ViewState["CurrentTable"] != null)
    {
        DataTable dtCurrentTable = (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentTable"];
        DataRow drCurrentRow = null;
        if (dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <= dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                TextBox TextBoxsh = (TextBox)grvdocumentDetails.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[4].FindControl("txtsh");
                DropDownList DrpStatus = (DropDownList)grvdocumentDetails.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[5].FindControl("drpStatus");
                DropDownList DrpClass = (DropDownList)grvdocumentDetails.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[6].FindControl("drpClass");
                drCurrentRow = dtCurrentTable.NewRow();
                drCurrentRow["RowNumber"] = i + 1;

                dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["Col1"] = Docprpp[0];
                dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["Col2"] = Docprpp[1];
                dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["Col3"] = Docprpp[2];
                dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["Col4"] = TextBoxsh.Text;
                dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["Col5"] = DrpStatus.SelectedValue;
                dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["Col6"] = DrpClass.SelectedValue;
                rowIndex++;
            }
            dtCurrentTable.Rows.Add(drCurrentRow);
            ViewState["CurrentTable"] = dtCurrentTable;

            grvdocumentDetails.DataSource = dtCurrentTable;
            grvdocumentDetails.DataBind();

        }
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Write("ViewState is null");
    }

    Docprpp.Clear();
    SetPreviousData();

}

 private void SetPreviousData()
{
    int rowIndex = 0;
    if (ViewState["CurrentTable"] != null)
    {
        DataTable dt = (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentTable"];
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                Label TextBoxDoc = (Label)grvdocumentDetails.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].FindControl("txtDoc");
                Label TextBoxRev = (Label)grvdocumentDetails.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[2].FindControl("txtRev");
                Label TextBoxtitle = (Label)grvdocumentDetails.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[3].FindControl("txttitle");
                TextBox TextBoxsh = (TextBox)grvdocumentDetails.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[4].FindControl("txtsh");
                DropDownList DrpStatus = (DropDownList)grvdocumentDetails.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[5].FindControl("drpStatus");
                DropDownList DrpClass = (DropDownList)grvdocumentDetails.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[6].FindControl("drpClass");
                // drCurrentRow["RowNumber"] = i + 1;

                grvdocumentDetails.Rows[i].Cells[0].Text = Convert.ToString(i + 1);
                TextBoxDoc.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Col1"].ToString();
                TextBoxRev.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Col2"].ToString();
                TextBoxtitle.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Col3"].ToString();
                TextBoxsh.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Col4"].ToString();
                DrpStatus.SelectedValue = dt.Rows[i]["Col5"].ToString();
                DrpClass.SelectedValue = dt.Rows[i]["Col6"].ToString();

                rowIndex++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: how many records in your data?

Answer (score 1):

move your Docprpp creation/initialization into AddNewRow(), and don't use static.

Comment: in the AddnewRow() it sets all the old rows and new row according last value for value Docprpp.i still have problem same rows,please explain with code